# Simulate chat messages on my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, web

how can I display text line after line, with seconds of timeshifting. 
The User should not be able to answer. 
I want to simulate chat messages.

Comment: Yes. And if you show us the code you've done so far, someone might be able to help.

Comment: Maybe I added no code because I do not know how to it, which will explain why I asked this question.

Comment: And here is a page which gives suggestions on how to ask questions - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You have to have some code to share, so someone can help you. For example, you already have a page, can you give us a part of the page where you would like a pseudo-chatbox to be/popup? Should there be text in it for the user to see? What is the text?

Comment: It is going to be a blank 404 site and there should be nothing, except some text like a conversation. I just want to know how I can display one line of text seconds after another line of tet. There is no special thingy like popups or something. Thats why I did not write anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p3Yh6/2/) will get you started.

1. An array of random phrases
2. A timer function that reads them randomly and places them in a div.

JS

```
var randomphrases = ['We the people','in order to form','a more perfect union','establish justice','insure domestic tranquility','provide for the common defence, promote the general welfare','and secure the blessings of liberty','to ourselves','and our posterity','do ordain and establish this constitution','of the United States of America'];

var c = 0;
var t;
var timer_is_on = 0;

timedCount();

function timedCount()
{
 t = setTimeout( function(){ timedCount() }, 1500 );
 random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (11 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
 $('.putmehere').html( randomphrases[random]);

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up with this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JumperKenny/eE8FR/1/) which works exactly how I want to.